# Nuxt: Vue Instance for Global Events

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'd like to use a separate `Vue` instance to handle events. This approach works in a standard `Vue` app but throws an error in the `Nuxt` environment.

Do I need to simply reference it differently?

**Code**

```
const Vue = require('vue');
const Hub = new Vue();

export default Hub;

// Usage
import Hub from '~/events/hub';

Hub.$emit(EVENT_TOGGLE_NAVIGATION, true);
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor
```

**Environment**

- `nuxt 1.0.0`
- `vue 2.5.17`

Comment: import Vue from 'vue'

Comment: Ah. So simple. Leave this as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use import

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```